# C++ combining 2 arrays, with data ordered

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

say I have 2 arrays.

```
double Array1[5][2] = {
{0.5 , 0.05},
{1.0 , 0.06},
{1.5 , 0.07},
{2.0 , 0.075},
{3.0 , 0.085}};

double Array2[2][2] = {
{2.5 , 0.08},
{3.5 , 0.105}};
```

Is there a way of combining the 2 arrays to that they are in order. eg.

```
double Array3[7][2] = {
{0.5 , 0.05},
{1.0 , 0.06},
{1.5 , 0.07},
{2.0 , 0.075},
{2.5 , 0.08},
{3.0 , 0.085}
{3.5 , 0.105}};
```

I keep going around in circles with for loops

Comment: merge sorting is the algorithm

Comment: you need to define the required order. should it be ordered according to the first element of each pair? the second? both with first, second priority?

Comment: ordered by the 1st element, as displayed in array3

Comment: @DAG The algorithm will be merging, which is commonly used as part of merge sort. There seems no "split" part here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  std::array<double, 2> Array1[5] = {
    { 0.5 , 0.05 },
    { 1.0 , 0.06 },
    { 1.5 , 0.07 },
    { 2.0 , 0.075 },
    { 3.0 , 0.085 }
  };

  std::array<double, 2> Array2[2] = {
    { 2.5 , 0.08 },
    { 3.5 , 0.105 }
  };
  std::array<double, 2> Array3[7];
  std::merge(std::begin(Array1), std::end(Array1), std::begin(Array2), std::end(Array2), Array3, [](const auto &a, const auto &b) {
    return a[0] < b[0];
  });
```

**ADDED**

the same with vectors:

```
  std::vector<std::array<double, 2>> Array1 = {
    { 0.5 , 0.05 },
    { 1.0 , 0.06 },
    { 1.5 , 0.07 },
    { 2.0 , 0.075 },
    { 3.0 , 0.085 }
  };

  std::vector<std::array<double, 2>> Array2 = {
    { 2.5 , 0.08 },
    { 3.5 , 0.105 }
  };
  std::vector<std::array<double, 2>> Array3;
  std::merge(std::begin(Array1), std::end(Array1), std::begin(Array2), std::end(Array2), std::back_inserter(Array3), [](auto &a, auto &b) {
    return a[0] < b[0];
  });
```

Comment: If I wanted to use <vector>, instead of <array> how would I do this

Comment: @Fitzy: it's easy, see my addition

Comment: @AnotolyS VSE 2013 is giving me the error "auto &: a parameter cannot have a type that contains auto' amd 'subscript requires array or pointer type'.

Comment: you can replace 'auto&' on 'const std::array<double>&'